# Angular 8 - filtering before a subscribe, does it fire it if the filter returns null?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm continuing a project from a former Coworker, and he coded something in a way I never saw, could someone help me out understanding the reasoning behind it?

```
this.loginState.User
      .pipe(filter(u => !!u))   // what on earth is this
      .subscribe(u => {
        if (!u.isAuthenticated && !u.hasLocalPassword .....
```

so basically this code block checks if there is an active user signed in, but that `filter(u => !!u)` is not clear to me.
To me that would be equal to:

```
 this.loginState.User
          .subscribe(u => {
             if (u) {
               if (!u.isAuthenticated && !u.hasLocalPassword .....
             }
```

basically wrapping my code after the subscribe in a `if (u)` .
Am I wrong and that is not the same, and there are actually benefits in doing it like that with the filter?

Thank you

Comment: Your version is exactly equivalent. The `filter` operator stops values from continuing through an observable pipe. I'd say both versions are fine here, and which you prefer depends on your preferences. Using a `filter` in the same way across your codebase would give your code some consistency and is easier to read. It also integrates nicely with other pipe operators. I personally find the `if(u)` a little ugly and would prefer the `filter` here, but both are functionally equivalent in your example.

Comment: ok great, now it's more clear, I'll continue using filter then and get used to this syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in the comments, putting the condition in the `filter` should be (and in your case is) equivalent to having that logic in subscribe.

---

It is a very good idea to get used to using the operators. Your goal should stop using the subscribe unless necessary (**use in template [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)** instead).

If it is necessary for you to subscribe, then try to achieve subscriptions without the logic. that would mean putting every operation in the pipable operators combining it in a way that it declaratively states what is going on.

An example of logic-less subscribe would be:

```js
// myObs$: Observable<Value[]>;

myObs$.pipe(
  filter(values => values.length > 0),
  map(values => values.map(val => val * 2)),
  tap(values => doSomeSideEffect(values)),
).subscribe();
```